# Getting certain rows from list of rows(C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a datatable having 44 rows.

I have converted that to list and want to take the rows from 4th row till the last(i.e. 44th).

I have the below program

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> lstDr = dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(4).Take(dt.Rows.Count);
```

But the output is `Enumeration yielded no results`

I am using c#3.0

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to take *everything* from the 4th row onwards, you don't need a Take call at all, just:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> lstDr = dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(4);
```

When you talk about "the output" what's that coming from? What do you get if you call:

```
Console.WriteLine(lstDr.Count());
```

?

How many rows are in your data table to start with?